# Keep lines only if a column is repeated three times within the file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a column file and I want to keep the lines that contain the **second column** repeated exactly three times within the file.

Input:

```
000 BBB PPP DDD
111 BBB SSS 444
777 CCC RRR 555
222 BBB 555 666
321 AAA YYY MMM
123 CCC LLL MMM
OOO AAA BBB VVV
545 UUU 321 R32
PPP AAA HHH TTT
```

Desired output

```
000 BBB PPP DDD
111 BBB SSS 444
222 BBB 555 666
321 AAA YYY MMM
OOO AAA BBB VVV
PPP AAA HHH TTT
```

I have searched on the internet but nothing similar found. Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  cntIndArray[$2]++
  valArray[$2]=(valArray[$2]?valArray[$2] ORS:"")$0
} 
END{
  for(i in cntIndArray){
    if(cntIndArray[i]==3){
      print valArray[i]
    }
  }
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                    ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  cntIndArray[$2]++                                      ##Creating array which keep trakcs of 2nd field occurence in lines.
  valArray[$2]=(valArray[$2]?valArray[$2] ORS:"")$0      ##Creating array which keeps adding same 2nd field lines concatinating with a new line.
} 
END{                                                     ##Starting END block of this code here.
  for(i in cntIndArray){                                 ##Traversing through array which has field count here.
    if(cntIndArray[i]==3){                               ##Checking if an element value equals 3 then do following.
      print valArray[i]                                  ##Printing array value with index i which has exact line value in it.
    }
  }
}'  Input_file                                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you need output to be in same sequence in which 2nd field occurs in Input_file then try following.

```
awk '
!seen[$2]++{
  cntIndArray[++count]=$2
}
{
  cntArray[$2]++;
  valArray[$2]=(valArray[$2]?valArray[$2] ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    if(cntArray[cntIndArray[i]]==3){
      print valArray[cntIndArray[i]]
    }
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]++;next} a[$2]==3' file{,}

000 BBB PPP DDD
111 BBB SSS 444
222 BBB 555 666
321 AAA YYY MMM
OOO AAA BBB VVV
PPP AAA HHH TTT
```

note that this is a double pass approach, if the content is in a file works better (small files doesn't matter, very large files this will work but internally keeping the data might not).  If the data is piped in this approach will not work.